# Ordenar Fichero-Archivo

Tags: java, archivo

Hola mi problema es que tengo que ordenar los registros de un fichero.dat por su id o en este caso su numero de control, mas especifico no consigo extraer los id de forma que los pueda comparar uno con otro en un if().
Mi fichero esta conformado por:

String (8+2 bytes) numero de control.

String (30+2 bytes) nombre.

Byte (1 byte) Status.

TR=43

Metodo Ordenar (Incompleto)

```
void Ordenar(){
    boolean ban=true;
    try{
    for(int pas=1;ban;pas++){
        ban=false;
        for(int com=1;com<=((canal.length())/TR);com++){
            canal.seek((com-1)*TR);
            if(N1.compareTo(N2)<0){
                canal.seek((com-1)*TR);


                ban=true;
            }
        }
    }
    }catch(IOException e){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error"+e);  
    }

}
```

no consigo comparar los numeros de control.
entiéndase que N1 y N2 NO son variables, hace referencia al numero de control 1 y el numero de control 2
Espero haber sido claro con mi situacion

Comment: Hola, deberías brindar un poco más de información sobre esas referencias N1 y N2

Comment: N1 y N2 son mis número de control que deseo comparar, mi problema principal es que no consigo extraer esos datos de mi archivo, cómo puedes observar no tengo inicializadas esas variables, únicamente las puse como ejemplo. Espero haber sido claro

Comment: ok, pasa que después pusiste "no consigo comparar los numeros de control", entonces pensé que era un problema con el `compareTo()`

Comment: y justo yo con los ficheros no tengo mucho conocimiento, pero sabes leer ese fichero? A ver si te puedo ayudar a guardar cada linea en un `array` o `ArrayList` para luego recorrerlo

Answer (score 0):

Acá va un ejemplito para que veas como funciona el `compareTo()` y lo adaptes a tu código.
No des importancia al nombre de la clase, es que tomé el proyecto que tenía a mano.

```
//Debes implementar interfaz Comparable, y a partir de allí estás obligado a sobreescribir su
//método abstracto compareTo()
public class PruebaArrays implements Comparable{
    //debe ser Integer, ya que el compareTo() no puede referenciar el tipo int
    private Integer id;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PruebaArrays pa1 =new PruebaArrays();
        pa1.setId(1);
        PruebaArrays pa2 =new PruebaArrays();
        pa2.setId(5);
        System.out.println("id pa1: "+pa1.getId());
        System.out.println("id pa2: "+pa2.getId());
        System.out.println("retorno de pa2.compareTo(pa1): "+pa2.compareTo(pa1));
        System.out.println("retorno de pa1.compareTo(pa2): "+pa1.compareTo(pa2));
        System.out.println("*** creo terer objeto con id igual a pa1 ***");

        PruebaArrays pa3 =new PruebaArrays();
        pa3.setId(1);
        System.out.println("retorno de pa3.compareTo(pa1): "+pa3.compareTo(pa1));
        //conclusión: para el método compareTo() los objetos pa1 y pa3 son iguales (devuelve 0)
        //ya que al sobreescribirlo le indiqué que el criterio de comparación es el id       
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        PruebaArrays pa =(PruebaArrays)o;//casting
        return this.getId().compareTo(pa.getId());//criterio
    }   
}
```